# How to Convert STRING to DATETIME in BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I Have `TS` column in `data table` which contains String Like this '20220205183013', I want to convert it to datetime format like this 2022-02-05 18:20:18 UTC.

I have tried this query but failed.

```
select CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as data_k from data_
```

and

```
select PARSE_DATETIME("%a %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S",ts)  from data_
```

but it still failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` here with the correct format mask:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', '20220205183013');
```

The mask you were using with `PARSE_DATETIME` does not match the input timestamp, which is in the format `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.